# Pydev : how to launch a main in a package?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've read a lot of subjects about pydev and problems about imported modules, but i haven't found the solution yet. Here is my problem.

I've created a Pydev project (Eclipse Oxygen, Python 3.6) with the following files tree :

```
myPyDevProject
|-src
   |-aPackage
      |-aSubPackage
      |  |-__init__.py
      |  |-myUtilClass.py
      |-__init__.py
      |-myMainApp.py
```

- I've added the "src" folder in the PYTHONPATH of the project.
- The `__init__.py` are empty.
- `myUtilClass.py` module defines the class MyUtilClass.
- `myMainApp.py` module contains only the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement creating an instance of the "MyUtilClass" class. It imports this class like this : `from aPackage.aSubPackage.myUtilClass import MyUtilClass`

Eclipse detects no problems.
But if I create a Python run configuration on the `myMainApp.py` module and launch it, I've got the following error :

```
    from aPackage.aSubPackage.myUtilClass import MyUtilClass

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aPackage.aSubPackage'; 'aPackage' is not a package
```

The "src" folder is really in the PYTHONPATH of the run configuration.
I've tried to change a lot of things in the run Configuration, but nothing works, like : add the "aPackage" folder in the PYTHONPATH, set the working directory on the "aPackage" or the "src" folders, ...

Have you an idea to fix this problem of run configuration ?

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: Check the run configuration's Working directory under the Arguments tab.  Is the working directory something like `${project_loc}/src`?  If not, try modifying it and run again.

Comment: Like i said, I've already tried to change the working directory, both selecting src or even aPackage, and got the same problem.